# Apple Configurator 2: Where are the Blueprints?

Tags: macos, apple-configurator

Apple Configurator 2 is scriptable with Automator, Apple-Script and Shell.
Nowhere it is though possible to invoke the blueprints I have defined in Configurator.
I can rebuild the contents of those blueprints within Automator, Apple-Script and Shell, but I cannot reuse, what I already built in Configurator.
Or am I wrong? Where are those blueprints?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding (which could be wrong) is that blueprints are for people that don't automate things. You pick from a palette of options and build up "automation" from within the app.

If you want to shell script, you would just install the `cfgutil` Automation tools and have your script written to perform the steps you want. Basically, the blueprint steps aren't exposed to the command line tool in the current design of the app. If you want to use both, you'll have to set up your scripts and blueprints redundantly which is more work, more chance for error and more maintenance. Whether you make that time back depends on how many devices you have to manage and how efficient you are at setting things up.

- http://krypted.com/iphone/apple-configurator-2/